# Manually controlled size of delimiters in macros

Tags: amsmath, delimiters

I am using the `amsmath` package and I'd like to control the size of my delimiters manually, i.e. using the
`\bigl`, `\Bigl`, ... , `\Bigr`, `\bigr` commands, instead of `\left`, `\middle`, `\right`.

Now I want to create macros which include delimiters and I want to have the size as an argument. For example, if I have a `\set` macro:

```
\newcommand{\set}[2]{ \left\{ #1 \,\middle\vert\, #2\right\} }
```

I want to change it into a command, where I can give the size as an argument, i.e.

```
\set{A}{B}{Big}
```

should produce `\Bigl\{ A \,\Big\vert\, B\Bigr\}` or, even better, `\set{A}{B}{2}` produces this result.

Is there any command like `\leftdelimitersize` to implement this kind of macros?

Comment: The `mathtools` package has features that should help you.

Comment: And also [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25328/use-csname-endcsname-to-compute-the-starred-version-of-some-command). Which has a different way of implementing it than the `mathtools` package.

Comment: Something here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100966/defining-scalable-white-curly-brackets-and-and/100993#100993 might help.  In that case, `\scalerel` was used, but if you wish to define the size, the sister routine `\scaleto` or `\stretchto` might suffice.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The package `mathtools` already provides the necessary features; you just have to add the possibility of using numbers instead of the commands `\big` and siblings.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\DeclarePairedDelimiterX{\innset}[2]{\lbrace}{\rbrace}{%
  #1\;\delimsize\vert\;#2}

\newcommand{\set}[3][0]{%
  \ifcase#1\relax
    \innset{#2}{#3}\or         % 0
    \innset[\big]{#2}{#3}\or   % 1
    \innset[\Big]{#2}{#3}\or   % 2
    \innset[\bigg]{#2}{#3}\or  % 3
    \innset[\Bigg]{#2}{#3}     % 4
  \else
    \innset*{#2}{#3}
  \fi}

\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
\set{A}{\frac{B}{C}}\\
\set[0]{A}{\frac{B}{C}}\\
\set[1]{A}{\frac{B}{C}}\\
\set[2]{A}{\frac{B}{C}}\\
\set[3]{A}{\frac{B}{C}}\\
\set[4]{A}{\frac{B}{C}}\\
\set[-1]{A}{\frac{B}{C}}
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

With a number not in the range 0–4, the version with `\left`, `\middle` and `\right` would be used.

[image]

Comment: The numbers are much more memorable than the names!

Answer (score 11):

If you are prepared to take something like `Big` as an argument then a simple solution to your request is to use `\csname ...\endcsname` to generate command names as needed, e.g.,

```
\newcommand\set[3]{\csname #3l\endcsname\{#1%
                   \,\csname#3\endcsname\vert\,%
                   #2\csname #3r\endcsname\}}
```

If you want to generate the needed commands via a numerical argument consider using `\ifcase`.