# Using LaTeX3 syntax in document commands

Tags: latex3, semantics

I have already read much about LaTeX3 on TeX.SE, in TeX Live’s documentation and in TUGBoat, but there is something I do not yet understand: is the expl3 syntax meant to be used in document-level commands?

I would be truly delighted if it was possible to include the caracthers `:` and `_` in command names defined with `\newcommand` or an equivalent LaTeX3 definition construct. That would bring “namespaces in the document”, so to speak, and generally make commands more readable (in my opinion). Since I always have to work with XML and HTML in my professional life, I would like to make my LaTeX markup more similar to XML’s elements and attributes, *at least superficially*.

Going further down this line of thinking, a side question is: is it somehow possible to use non-ASCII letters in LaTeX3 command names?

P.S.: Yes, I do pursue the foolish dream of *semantic markup in LaTeX* :-).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, that is to misunderstand the idea more or less completely :-) The 'long term vision' is that the 'machinery' is coded in `expl3`, while *one* interface is provided using LaTeX2e-like commands as at present. Note that one aim is to allow alternative interface layers backed by the same code: you might implement one of those of course.

You can use non-'letter' characters in command names, for example in 'classical' TeX:

```
\expandafter\def\csname some-awkward-1-2-3-name\endcsname
```

or in `expl3`:

```
\cs_set:cpn { some-awkward-1-2-3-name }
```

but accessing those 'readily' is not easy as TeX's rules mean that what is a 'letter' is important. Those rules can't be altered by macro packages, which includes `expl3`, so they remain in place.

Comment: I must thank you! This is exactly what I needed to hear. You see, even by documenting myself and trying to get the gist of LaTeX3, I had not gotten *that*, which is fundamental. As for a satisfying alternative, I was already aware of [this question about formatting and semantics](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103531/how-to-balance-being-semantic-and-retaining-control-of-formatting), where the accepted answer gives great insights, but I still wanted to ask my naïve question just to make sure.